# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Tags: json, ruby

I have a script called `import.rb` which will import json content from url to drafts directory.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'json'

# Load JSON data from source
# (Assuming the data source is a json file on your file system)
data = JSON.parse('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec')

# Proceed to create post files if the value array is not empty
array = data["user"]
if array && !array.empty?
  # create the `_drafts` directory if it doesn't exist already
  drafts_dir = File.expand_path('./_drafts', __dir__)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(posts_dir) unless Dir.exist?(drafts_dir)

  # iterate through the array and generate draft-files for each entry
  # where entry.first will be the "content" and entry.last the "title"
  array.each do |entry|
    File.open(File.join(drafts_dir, entry.last), 'wb') do |draft|
      draft.puts("---\n---\n\n#{entry.first}"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `ruby _scripts/import.rb` I get `_scripts/import.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
    end` error. I changed line from recommended form to `data = JSON.parse('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec')`. Original was `data = JSON.parse(File.read(your_json_source.json))`. Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lacking `)` at the end of 19 line:

```
 ...

 array.each do |entry|
   File.open(File.join(drafts_dir, entry.last), 'wb') do |draft|
     draft.puts("---\n---\n\n#{entry.first}")
   end
 end
```

it should resolve the issue :)

Comment: Now I get `unexpected token at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec' (JSON::ParserError)`

Comment: @FunMedia a URL is not JSON. If you want to access the JSON at the url, you have to use a http client to retrieve it, then parse the response body (see [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client))

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Can I use like `data = JSON.parse(open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec'))` also a `require 'open-uri'`. Now I get `no implicit conversion of StringIO into String (TypeError)`